# How did these three characters die?

Tags: plot-explanation, teachers-2001

Season 4 Episode 1 of *[Teachers](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0280330/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)* has some of the characters visiting the graves of three characters from the previous three seasons:

> Kurt, Brian, and Matt.

In the synopsis on IMDB it says they died in a car crash. I didn't hear anything during the episode that specifically said it was a car crash that killed them. Is there some other source the IMDB synopsis got its information from? Was there perhaps a "Christmas Special" episode or similar, something shown between the seasons but not available on Netflix for some reason?

Comment: [the shark is jumped within minutes of the first episode of series four. The few characters that do remain go to visit the graves of Kurt, Matt and Brian, who apparently all died in an off-screen car crash](https://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/2018/sep/10/see-me-after-class-how-teachers-flunked-out) See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Teachers_(British_TV_series)_characters .

Comment: BCdotWEB so the information about the car crash comes from promotional material published at the time the episode aired? I'm guessing it would be common knowledge in the UK (if you were interested in the programme) and didn't need to be specifically said in the episode to be listed as a fact in a recap of the episode? I'll accept that as an answer if you want to write it. (And yes, I'm only watching series 4 for completeness, it's really not good!)

Comment: Are you sure it isn't casually mentioned in the episode? I remember watching the first two seasons of Teachers back then and loving it, but I'm not even sure I watched the third series. (While looking into this I was pleasantly surprised to discover Raquel Cassidy was part of its cast; now I realize why she looked familiar in Downton Abbey.)

Comment: Yes, I went back and rewatched the episode specifically because I thought I had missed it. And yes, there are quite a few people at the start of their careers (eg James Cordern playing a student).